# Adjacency list representation of graph

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, tree

It was mentioned in the below answer that adjacency list representation of sparse graph with 1000 vertices can store 2997 values.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12599289/3184755
But I can only think the answer is 999*2 = 1998 because number of edges in a tree of 'n' nodes is n-1 and in adjacency list of undirected graph will have 2 * no. of edges.
Please explain how the value is 2997 for sparse graph? Also how the value is 3000000 for dense graph?

Typing it from my phone so couldn't format the answer

Comment: I think you're right, and you should probably leave this as a comment under that answer.

Comment: The linked answer talks about how many 'values' you have to store, not 'edges'.  If you're careful about space you can store the adjacency list for the tree by packing the lists into one array (1998 values), sorting lists by vertex number, and using another array of 999 values to link each vertex to its start in the array.  999 because you know that the first vertex starts at index 0

Comment: https://iq.opengenus.org/graph-representation-adjacency-matrix-adjacency-list/   Read this link, and also note the difference between the directed graph and undirected graph. I think the link you mentioned is talking about the undirected graph.

Comment: @MattTimmermans I didn't undersnad completely. Can you pls elaborate or explain it using an example?